# VBA macro to export XML which avoids a row if a certain cells is "OFF" value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro that prints my data out as an XML.  I'm trying to figure out a way to edit my macro to skip a row during the loop if a certain cell value is "OFF". Since I'm not great at writing VBA code, I wanted to keep this simple so I look up vba macros and fiddle with them until I get the desired result so apologies for any mistakes I have in the code provided.  Here's the macro I have now but I keep getting a mismatch type error.  For each row of the XML, I have a cell next to it that is either set to the "ON" or "OFF" value.  Thanks for the help everyone!

```
Sub Export_tvXML()

Dim XMLFileName As String

Dim MetaFileName1 As String
Dim MetaFileName2 As String

Dim output1 As String
Dim output2 As String

Dim range1 As Range
Dim range2 As Range

Set range1 = Sheets("XML").Range("A2:E84")
Set range2 = Sheets("XML").Range("A86:E168")

MetaFileName1 = Sheets("TV_Info").Range("G5")
MetaFileName2 = Sheets("TV_Info").Range("G6")


XMLFileName = MetaFileName1 & ".xml"

For Each r In range1.Rows
    If Cells(r, 6).Value = 1 Then
        For Each c In r.Cells
            output1 = output1 & c.Value
        Next c
        output1 = output1 & vbNewLine
    End If
Next r

Open XMLFileName For Output As #1
Print #1, output1
Close #1


XMLFileName = MetaFileName2 & ".xml"

For Each r In range2.Rows
    For Each c In r.Cells
        output2 = output2 & c.Value
    Next c
    output2 = output2 & vbNewLine
Next r

Open XMLFileName For Output As #2
Print #2, output2
Close #2


End Sub
```

As for the spreadsheet side of it, I have mocked up XMLs and the macro will just output the value as it's formatted.  Here's a screenshot for reference.  So any row that is set to off, I want the macro to skip that row and move onto to the next row that's on to output it.

[XML Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JynWW.png)

Comment: Do not concatenate XML strings as a text file. Use the MSXML library which maintains [DOM Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757828(v=vs.85).aspx): `createElement()`, `appendChild()`, `setAttributeNode()`....

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the following line:

```
If Cells(r, 6).Value = 1 Then
```

You are testing the cell value against a number (1), but you mean to test against a string value, which is why you get the type mismatch.

Try changing it to the following:

```
If StrComp(Cells(r, 6).Value,"ON")=0 Then
```

StrComp is a useful function to compare two strings, which includes options to make the comparison case-insensitive. In this case, the two strings are the contents of successive cells in column 6, and the string "ON".